# Resolve array of observables and append in final array

Tags: rxjs

I have an endpoint url like http://site/api/myquery?start=&limit= which returns an array of strings.
If I call this endpoint in this way, the server hangs since the array of strings length is huge.

I need to generate an an array of observables with incremental "start" and "limit" parameters, resolve all of then either in sequence or in parallel, and then get a final observable which at the end yields the true array of strings, obtained merging all the subarray of strings returned by the inner observables.

How should I do that?

i.e. the array of observables would be something like

```
[
    httpClient.get(http://site/api/myquery?start=0&limit=1000),
    httpClient.get(http://site/api/myquery?start=1000&limit=1000),
    httpClient.get(http://site/api/myquery?start=2000&limit=1000),
    ....
]
```

Comment: Do you know the overall limit of items before making these calls?

Comment: Yes I do, I can query the metadata to get the total count (which is the length of the what I called the "array of strings")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the length before making all these queries — then you can create as many http-get Observables as you need, and then `forkJoin` them using projection fn.

`forkJoin` will let you make parallel queries and then merge results of those queries. Heres an example:

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

// given we know the length:
const LENGTH = 500;
// we can pick arbitrary page size
const PAGE_SIZE = 50;

// calculate requests count
const requestsCount = Math.ceil(LENGTH / 50);

// generate calculated number of requests
const requests = (new Array(requestsCount))
  .fill(void 0)
  .map((_,i) => {
    const start = i * PAGE_SIZE;
    return http.get(`http://site/api/myquery?start=${start}&limit=${PAGE_SIZE}`);
  });

forkJoin(
  requests,

  // projecting fn
  // merge all arrays into one
  // suboptimal merging, just for example
  (...results) => results.reduce(((acc, curr)=> [...acc, ...curr]) , [])
).subscribe(array => {
  console.log(array);
})
```

Check this [forkJoin example](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/forkJoin/) for reference.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you do not know the total number of items, you can do this using [expand](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html).

The following article gives a good introduction to `expand` and an explanation of how to use it for pagination.

https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/

Something along the lines of the code below would work in your case, making the requests for each page in series.

```
const limit = 1000;
let currentStart = 0;

let getUrl = (start, limit) => `http://site/api/myquery?start=${start}&limit=${limit}`;

httpClient.get(getUrl(currentStart, limit)).pipe(
  expand(itemsArray => {
    if (itemsArray.length) {
      currentStart += limit;
      return httpClient.get(getUrl(currentStart, limit));
    }

    return empty();
  }),
  reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, ...value]),
).subscribe(itemsArray => { 
    console.log(itemsArray); 
})
```

This will log out the final array of items once the entire series of requests has been resolved.